# Firebase take an exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I make an a realtime databse with users registration:

```
set(ref(db, 'users/' + res.data.localId), {          
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            email: email,
            countTrains: 0
          }).then(() => {
             console.log('Made new account');    
        })  
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Also i need to update my *countTrains*. In the other Stack Navigator screen i try:

```
function update () {
    update(ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId), {          
      countTrains: countTrain,
    }).then(() => {
      // Data saved successfully!
      alert('data updated!');    
  })  
      .catch((error) => {
          // The write failed...
          alert(error);
      });
  };
```

**But take an excetpion: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, js engine: hermes**

Comment: This exception takes only with the function update, if i try to overwrite from scratch the data again, it works